# OpenWeatherMap API returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, json, openweathermap

My previous questions lacked clarity, so I'll try to be clear as much as possible.
I'm trying to create a weather app but every time I try to `fetch` information (JSON Format) it returns undefined. I am using pure vanilla JavaScript and trying to load Open Weather Map's API. I tried using another API (Free Weather API) but that returned undefined as well. Please note that the websites are loading properly I think its just a problem with my code.

```
fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Traralgon&appid=a211b9a621afd7714296d94616623dea&units=metric').then(function (response) {
    console.log('success!', response.main);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

Comment: I've just removed that API key I used in my code from my API key library. In other words, that API key will not work anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but when I open the link in my browser it shows a JSON file white all the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way promise works, you need to transform the response and pass this transform through to the next `then` pipe.

```
fetch(
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Traralgon&appid=a211b9a621afd7714296d94616623dea&units=metric'
  )
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (responseJSON) {
      console.log('success!', responseJSON.main);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
```

Explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

We should use `json()` method on the response object before doing any kind of operation on the data. Actually `json()` method takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise . So for consuming the promise returned by `response.json()` we should use `.then()` method. On resolving it parses the body text as JSON.

```
fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Traralgon&appid=a211b9a621afd7714296d94616623dea&units=metric')
        .then(function (response) {
           // parsing the body of response object
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('sucess', response.main);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
```